# Index on view with 3 joined table is not working

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, indexed-view

I have Microsoft SQL Server 2019. I want to create a view that includes 3 tables, then create an index on it to use it in query.

When I do this on 2 tables, all works fine, but with 3 tables in the view, it does not work (all created correctly, but index isn't used in queries).

For example: I have these 3 tables: `test`, `test_item`, `test_item_code`

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS dbo.test_view1;
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS dbo.test_view2;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DB_TEMP.dbo.test_item_code;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DB_TEMP.dbo.test_item;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DB_TEMP.dbo.test;

CREATE TABLE DB_TEMP.dbo.test 
(
    t_id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    t_time datetime NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_test PRIMARY KEY (t_id)
);

CREATE TABLE DB_TEMP.dbo.test_item 
(
    ti_id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    ti_t_id int NOT NULL,
    ti_name nvarchar(100) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT PK_test_item PRIMARY KEY (ti_id)
);

ALTER TABLE DB_TEMP.dbo.test_item 
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_test_item 
        FOREIGN KEY (ti_t_id) REFERENCES DB_TEMP.dbo.test(t_id);

CREATE TABLE DB_TEMP.dbo.test_item_code 
(
    tic_id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    tic_ti_id int NOT NULL,
    tic_code varchar(10) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE DB_TEMP.dbo.test_item_code 
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_test_item_code 
        FOREIGN KEY (tic_ti_id) REFERENCES DB_TEMP.dbo.test_item(ti_id);
```

When I create indexed view on two of them

```
CREATE VIEW test_view1 
WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS
    SELECT ti_name, t_id, ti_id, t_time
    FROM dbo.test_item
    INNER JOIN dbo.test ON t_id = ti_t_id 
    WHERE ti_name > '';
GO 

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX PK_test_view1 
ON test_view1 (ti_id);

CREATE INDEX IDX_test_view1 
ON test_view1 (ti_name, t_time) INCLUDE (t_id);
```

It worked fine. Plan for query

```
SELECT TOP 10 t_time  
FROM test_view1 
WHERE ti_name = 'name1' 
ORDER BY t_time DESC;
```

is using the index `IDX_test_view1`.

But for indexed view with 3 tables:

```
CREATE VIEW test_view2 
WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS
    SELECT tic_code, tic_id, ti_id, t_id, t_time
    FROM dbo.test_item_code
    INNER JOIN dbo.test_item ON ti_id = tic_ti_id
    INNER JOIN dbo.test ON t_id = ti_t_id
    WHERE tic_code > '';
GO 

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX PK_test_view2 
ON test_view2 (tic_id);

CREATE INDEX IDX_test_view2 
ON test_view2 (tic_code, t_time) INCLUDE (t_id);
GO
```

This does not work. Plan for  query

```
SELECT TOP 10 t_time  
FROM test_view2 
WHERE tic_code = 'code1' 
ORDER BY t_time DESC
```

starts from 'Table scan test_item_code'... It doesn't use index `IDX_test_view2`. It used separate tables test_item_code, test_item, test and their indexes.

How to build a correctly indexed view for 3 tables?

Comment: Have you tried the `NOEXPAND` hint? `SELECT TOP 10 t_time  
FROM test_view2 WITH (NOEXPAND)
WHERE tic_code = 'code1' 
ORDER BY t_time DESC`

Comment: https://sqlperformance.com/2015/12/sql-performance/noexpand-hints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The optimizer will consider view indexes as part of query optimization in Enterprise and Developer editions but [index view matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table?view=sql-server-ver16#using-noexpand) does not always occur as expected even when the view is used directly in queries. It is sometimes necessary to specify the `NOEXPAND` table hint (which is required in lesser editions to use the view index).

```
SELECT TOP 10 t_time  
FROM test_view2 WITH (NOEXPAND)
WHERE tic_code = 'code1' 
ORDER BY t_time DESC;
```